# how to store same data in multiple $scope variables in same controller using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

I have to store same data in two different scope variables. I have saved as per below code.

```
    app.controller('ClientsCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

        $scope.model = {};

        $http.get("client/getdata", {})
            .then(function (result) {

                //For e.g, I have received result.data.Frequency = 'Weekly'

                $scope.model = {
                    edit: result.data,
                    show: result.data
                };

            },
            function (error) {
            });

    });
```

Used these scope variables to show and edit like

```
<div>        
    <div>
       Show Model Frequency: {{model.show.Frequency}}<br /><br />
       Edit Model Frequency: {{model.edit.Frequency}}
    </div>

    <div>
        <md-select ng-model="model.edit.Frequency" aria-label="Frequency">
            <md-option value="Daily"> Daily</md-option>
            <md-option value="Weekly"> Weekly</md-option>
        </md-select>
    </div>
</div>
```

If once I changed the value in edit model, its also auto change in show model even I stored in different variables.

I want to change the data only after save the data and don't want to display the changing frequency before save.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Because of they have same reference. So you need to create a new reference before the object assignation.

So use [angular.copy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy)

```
$scope.model = {edit:angular.copy(result.data),show:angular.copy(result.data)};
```

or try this

```
$scope.model = {
                edit:JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result.data)),
                show:JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result.data))
                };
```

Comment: or "edit: angular.copy(result.data)" should be also ok

Comment: @huanfeng Yes. I have updating that while you commenting :)